# I have one check box field on account which needs to be updated (True)

Tags: workbench

I have one check box field on account which needs to be updated (True) when i add any notes and attachment in record. I want to implement this functionality via workflow how can i achieve this.

Can anyone help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use workflow for these types of actions, but you can use the [Flow Builder](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/business_process_automation/flow) instead if you prefer to avoid using Apex.